# How do I find someone to install a utility pole?

Tags: installation, pole

I am in need of a fairly tall utility wooden pole installed on my property, which I'm sure requires special know how and equipment to do safely. I've been doing a lot of Googling and found a few companies around the country that SELL the poles, but not installers.

I'm not even sure what terms to search for exactly.

Does anyone have some guidance for how to find a contractor that does this kind of work?

BTW: I'm in Texas, USA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many utility arborists have digger trucks and install utility  poles.  You can also call your local power company and ask if they have any sub-contractors that install private poles. Good Luck

Comment: Power company was the right call. They pointed me to a subcontractor who gave me a quote. If anyone is interested it looks like it runs about $1350 to get a wooden utility pole installed in Texas if you don't have to dig through a lot of rock.